# Deployment with Entity Framework 3.5 in separate Project

Tags: deployment, frameworks, connection, entity

I have a site I am trying to get deployed. It has 3 projects in the solution.
1. **AvialtionModel** - Holds the Entity Model edmx 
2. **AviationOSL** - Holds the Object Service Layer objects to interact between the site and the model
3. **AviationWeb** - Web Site

Everything works fine using the Visual Studio Development Servers but when I try and deploy to IIS it acts like the Model can't get connected to the database. I have tried create a setup project, xcopy, web publishing and nothing seems to help with the connection. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous possible issues here:

1) The connection strings in web.config (which is where I assume that you are storing them) point to a machine that is not accessible from the deployed server. This could be because it points to . or (local) from the testing environment, but the database is not on the deployment machine.

2) The deployment machine does not have the client connection to the database machine configured or configured correctly (if using SQL Server, this is the cliconfg utility).

3) The deployment machine is in a DMZ or different domain and the database machine cannot be reached from the deployment machine. Try accessing the database machine directly from the deployment machine; this will let you know whether or not there is a "visibility" issue.

4) There is a firewall between the deployment machine and the development machine that does not have the SQL ports opened (the specific ports will depend on your client and server configurations).

5) If using integrated security for connectivity, there could be issues if you are not performing user impersonation on the deployment machine (this is a very broad topic, which I won't delve into at the moment).